# R - out of memory when converting to dummy variables

Tags: r, memory, dummy-variable

i have a data set with categorical variable with ugly number of levels (5000 or so).
When i ran my code to convert to dummy variables, it says it needs 22 gigs of memory and crashes

```
dmy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data = num_data)
new_data <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = num_data))
```

What should i do in this case? Go for cloud solution?
Try to optimize features?

Comment: use a sparse model matrix?  tell us more about what you're doing (e.g. how many observations do you have)?  Let us know that you're using the `caret` package?

Comment: Ok, so the problem is:
- there is a dataset with retail sales (broken down by visits)
- each row is visit number, visit type and category in which customer bought the products - categorical variable (so there are multiple rows with same visit number, visit type, but different categories, since customer might have bought many products across categories)
- the objective is to predict visit type based on categories from which customer bought product
- there are 600 000 rows (around 200 000 visits) and 5000 categories
So i'm trying to convert the product category variable for machine learning

Comment: You don't need to explain the history. We suggest you to use sparse.model.matrix and then try `glmnet` package with `cv.glmnet` function which support sparse input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try [`sparse.model.matrix`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/sparse.model.matrix.html)

Or extend your memory limits

```
 memory.limit(10*memory.limit())
```